# How to Create Proxy Service from WSDL That Requires HTTP Authentication to Access?

Tags: wso2, esb, wso2-esb

I'm trying to create a proxy service based on a WSDL hosted on another machine. In connecting to that machine to display the WSDL in my browser, I'm prompted to provide a username and password. The proxy configuration within WSO2 ESB does not allow me to provide any authentication details and so generating the service based on this WSDL fails.

Is there any way to allow WSO2 ESB to authenticate requests to this server by default so that it may retrieve the WSDL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply download the wsdl and add it from filesystem or registry when creating the proxy. You can find a [few options here](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/Publishing+a+WSDL).

If the backend service is secured, it's possible to pass the auth headers received at the ESB to the backend or send some stored credentials.

Answer (score 0):

@Rajeev but is there also away to send username:password in URI? Because this doesn't seen to work. For example: https://username:password@host:5443/Service/Service?wsdl SoapUI can do this but publishWSDL doesn't accept this structure.

This inline specification is workable for simple services but services that rely on a lot of schema definitions it is a bit of pain. As you also need to download those and map them.

So you actually want to be able to pass a username and password to the webserver hosting the WSDL.

Comment: No it doesn't but in my opinion it should. The URL is perfectly valid in this way and you want to be able to consume a WSDL from a webserver that has Basic Authentication enabled.

Comment: Perhaps raise an issue on JIRA